# WeMos D1 ESP-Wroom-02 Mother Board ESP8266 - where is reset pin for deep-sleep

Tags: esp8266, pins, sleep

This [item](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32860090110.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.70534c4dSBq9RI) was bought for battery use with deep sleep purposes. For doing so in ESP8266 `reset` pin must be connected to `Gnd` pin in order to wake up. This board lacks a `reset` on- board pin.
Since spec states it has a such capabilities - I wonder if someone has succeeded with putting it to sleep ( and wake it back on ).

PS - I know that on-chip `gpio16` can be soldered to on-chip `gnd` - I'm hoping there is a more elegant, not soldering invloved, solution.
Guy

Comment: So the board does not break out the reset pin. You can try to solder a wire to the reset button. But what is your actual question? Asking for a specific, cheap, bad documented one from aliexpress most likely will not lead to good results. The possibility, that someone else here used the exact same module, is very low. Also: Where does it state, that it has a broken out reset pin? I don't see anything like that on the site.

Comment: Both GPIO16 and RST are available on ESP-WROOM-02 module, see https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/0c-esp-wroom-02_datasheet_en.pdf.

Comment: @jsotola question is rephrased now.

Comment: @chrisl I hope question  is clearer now. I tried to create such "soldering" as you suggested - but a awke up did not occur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This support page has the instructions for enabling deep sleep:

[Support for WeMos D1 ESP-Wroom-02 Nodemcu](https://github.com/arendst/Tasmota/issues/1236)

edit by Guy: in short, solder/connect pins as shown circled in red:

[image: image of board]